# Is it possible to use both AppStore and InHouse profiles with the same app with push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

First of all, I apologize if I'm missing some fundamental understandings of the apple build/deployment model, I'm very new to this.

A little background - The app I'm involved with is an appstore-distributed app, but the company likes to be able distribute beta builds internally and/or to select customers before publishing to the appstore.  The adhoc distribution model doesn't really work for this (device ids are not known ahead of time) so we use the "InHouse" distribution model for this.  That means in the developer console we have 2 different 'organizations' - one that does the appstore build, and an 'enterprise' one that does the inhouse build.

The app itself is a "thin-ish" client which interacts with a back-end server for a significant amount of its functionality.  On the server side we have the production environment and we also have a public "pre-launch" environment.  The client can be configured to use either one of these environments (both beta and publicly-released client builds can consume either the production or pre-launch servers)

This all works fine.

But now, we're adding push notifications.  It seems straight forward - when the app connects to 1 environment it registers with it, and unregisters with the other...and thus the app only gets notifications from the environment it is (or was last) connected to.  However on the server/config side I don't know how to make it work.  Because apple doesn't support both inhouse and appstore profiles for the same organization these 2 builds are done by different 'organizations' and seen as different apps - how can I get these '2 applications' to be recognized as the same app, with the ability to send notifications to either of them using the same key from the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very similar setup on our system, an App Store distributed app and an In-House enterprise app for beta testing.  For push to work, you need to know which distribution channel was used and use the appropriate key.  The flow would look like this:

1. Enterprise-signed app gets `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`.
2. App sends registration to your server `{"device-token":token, "distribution": "enterprise"}`
3. Your server stores the pair of values in the database.
4. When an event triggers a notification, you look up who to send it to treating both the token and distribution type as the destination address.
5. When sending the notification, use the distribution type to select the key.  Use the token and everything else like you normally would.

As far as recognizing which version of your app is enterprise-signed versus the app store, you just need to have some way to detect it.  We use different bundle identifiers:

```
if ([[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.stackexchange.stackexchange"]) {
    return @"app-store";
} else {
    return @"enterprise";
}
```

You could similarly inject some sort of information into your Info.plist to help you distinguish the two.

Comment: aww shucks, I was hoping to not have to resort to this :)  Thanks